# Transformation of standard error as response ratio [SE(RR)] to SE logarithm response ratio [SE(lnRR)]

Tags: standard-error, meta-analysis

A meta-analysis reports its results as RR and relative SE. I need to convert these to logarithm response ratio and have SE(lnRR), instead of SE(RR). How do I convert SE? I don't think it's correct to do the ln of SE (also because the SE becomes negative).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Convert the end points of the CI as well and then back-calculate the SE.